# Task factory return result lost extension method

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, extension-methods

I have the following situation:

```
  List<Product> productsA = _productRepository.GetProductsA().ToList();
  List<Product> productsB = _productRepository.GetProductsB().ToList();
```

Than i have a extension method using both collections:

```
  productsA.CompareBeta<Produto>(productsB, new List<string> { "Cod" }, "Key");
```

And ok, it works perfectly.
But i want to change these repository methods using task factory.

```
  var productsA = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _productRepository.GetProductsA());
  var productsB = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => _productRepository.GetProductsB().ToList());
  Task.WaitAll(produtosTotvs, produtosLive);
```

It worked too. But now i cannot get my extension method. Is it possible to do?

Comment: What do you mean "I cannot get my extension method"? productsA & productsB are Tasks in your second example. Use `productsA.Result.CompareBeta()`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var productA = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Product>>(() => _productRepository.GetProductsA());
var productB = Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<Product>>(() => _productRepository.GetProductsB());
Task.WaitAll(produtosTotvs, produtosLive);

productsA.Result.CompareBeta<Produto>(productsB.Result, new List<string> { "Cod" }, "Key");
```

But that is a bad implementation of async!

Try replacing all of it for await async pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should try accessing the extension method by the task's result:

```
productsA.Result.CompareBeta<Produto>(productsB.Result, new List<string> { "Cod" }, "Key");
```

See more about [Task Result](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537613.aspx)